# Expanded accordion list items to stay in flex columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

In the demo below, there are two columns with list items and when I click on the #6 `li` in the column #2, the #5 `li` jumps to the column #1. Is there a way to make sure all 3 lists to STAY in the column #2 when clicked?

```js
$(function() {
  // (Optional) Active an item if it has the class "is-active" 
  $(".accordion > .accordion-item.is-active").children(".accordion-panel").slideDown();

  $(".accordion > .accordion-item").click(function() {
    // Cancel the siblings
    $(this).siblings(".accordion-item").removeClass("is-active").children(".accordion-panel").slideUp();
    // Toggle the item
    $(this).toggleClass("is-active").children(".accordion-panel").slideToggle("ease-out");
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap column;
  height: 200px; /*to change height to split ul list*/
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.accordion {
  list-style: none;
}

.accordion-thumb {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.accordion-thumb::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-out;
}

.accordion-panel {
  margin: -10px;
  display: none;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion">
  <li class="accordion-item is-active">
    <h3 class="accordion-thumb">1.) list one</h3>
    <p class="accordion-panel">1111111111
    </p>
  </li>

  <li class="accordion-item">
    <h3 class="accordion-thumb">2.) list two</h3>
    <p class="accordion-panel">2222222222 </p>
  </li>

  <li class="accordion-item">
    <h3 class="accordion-thumb">3.) list three</h3>
    <p class="accordion-panel">3333333333
    </p>
  </li>

  <li class="accordion-item">
    <h3 class="accordion-thumb">4.) list four </h3>
    <p class="accordion-panel">4444444444 </p>
  </li>

  <li class="accordion-item">
    <h3 class="accordion-thumb">5.) list five</h3>
    <p class="accordion-panel">5555555555
    </p>
  </li>

  <li class="accordion-item">
    <h3 class="accordion-thumb">6.) list six</h3>
    <p class="accordion-panel">6666666666 </p>
  </li>

  <li class="accordion-item">
    <h3 class="accordion-thumb">7.) list seven</h3>
    <p class="accordion-panel">7777777777
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a sollution using Column-count in the css

[demo](https://codepen.io/_Odinh/pen/bLEKBJ)

It does solve your problem in a different way

i've changed this from your example code

added a `<li>` between the fourth and fifth `<li>`

```
<li class="column-break">&nbsp;</li>
```

changed the css of the UL to:

```
    ul {
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  column-count: 2;
}
```

added css for the `<li>` with the class "column-break"

```
.column-break {
  break-after: column;
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work - I updated the demo - https://codepen.io/magnix/pen/eVJKzJ when I click on #6 `li` the #5 `li` jumps to the column #1

Comment: @ChristianLuneborg check this codepen out! https://codepen.io/_Odinh/pen/bLEKBJ
this does work though i have re-added the li item that has the column-break class and removed the height on the ul

Comment: Boy, I thought it didnt work after updating your codes and realized I had somebody else's code on the ul. It worked when I removed somebody's code. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

one ¿hacky? sollution is to change the height of the ul to 180px

Comment: LOL, that simply worked like charm. I was changing the height size back and forth. Thanks, man!

Comment: you could however use a multi column layout and use break after as well

Comment: Oh. Actually, it didn't work on my end. I'm using @media 480px and the #5 `li` continues to jump to column #2. Two columns will be enough to fit in the 480px version.

Answer (score 1):

The columns are created when the line items can no longer to fit within the confined height (200px). Once the column reaches enough items to fill up 200px, the next `li` is wrapped to the next column. When you click on the sixth `li`, it minimizes the 5th item. Those items are 38px high so five of them can easily fit into the first column (38 * 5 = 190) and thus the 5th item is wrapped into the first column.

Given the example and what you are trying to accomplish, you can either reduce the height of `ul` to `180px` and it will keep the three items in the second row. OR you can add top or bottom padding or margin or a fixed/min-height to the `li`.

Answer (score 1):

Updated after a comment.

Using `Flexbox` I see 1 way, by using one of the pseudo as a divider.

With the pseudo, it is positioned after the 4th item by simply give the first 4 `òrder: -1`. Then we give it 100% height, and as such it will force itself in a column of its own.

Furthermore, to avoid column wraps between the first 4 and last 3, the parent container must be high enough to accommodate all items in each column, plus either one's content (which, when using *accordion*, the container generally always is).

Stack snippet - Pseudo divider

```js
$(function() {
  // (Optional) Active an item if it has the class "is-active" 
  $(".accordion > .accordion-item.is-active").children(".accordion-panel").slideDown();

  $(".accordion > .accordion-item").click(function() {
    // Cancel the siblings
    $(this).siblings(".accordion-item").removeClass("is-active").children(".accordion-panel").slideUp();
    // Toggle the item
    $(this).toggleClass("is-active").children(".accordion-panel").slideToggle("ease-out");
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap column;
  height: 250px; /*to change height to split ul list*/
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.accordion {
  list-style: none;
}

.accordion::before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
}

.accordion-item:nth-child(-n+4) {
  order: -1;
}


.accordion-thumb {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.accordion-thumb::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-out;
}

.accordion-panel {
  margin: -10px;
  display: none;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion">
 <li class="accordion-item is-active">
  <h3 class="accordion-thumb">1.) list one</h3>
  <p class="accordion-panel">1111111111<br>3333333333<br>3333333333
  </p>
 </li>
 
 <li class="accordion-item">
  <h3 class="accordion-thumb">2.) list two</h3>
  <p class="accordion-panel">2222222222<br>3333333333<br>3333333333  </p>
 </li>
 
 <li class="accordion-item">
  <h3 class="accordion-thumb">3.) list three</h3>
  <p class="accordion-panel">3333333333<br>3333333333<br>3333333333
  </p>
 </li>
 
 <li class="accordion-item">
  <h3 class="accordion-thumb">4.) list four </h3>
  <p class="accordion-panel">4444444444<br>3333333333<br>3333333333  </p>
 </li>
 
 <li class="accordion-item">
  <h3 class="accordion-thumb">5.) list five</h3>
  <p class="accordion-panel">5555555555<br>3333333333<br>3333333333
  </p>
 </li>
 
 <li class="accordion-item">
  <h3 class="accordion-thumb">6.) list six</h3>
  <p class="accordion-panel">6666666666<br>3333333333<br>3333333333  </p>
 </li>
 
 <li class="accordion-item">
  <h3 class="accordion-thumb">7.) list seven</h3>
  <p class="accordion-panel">7777777777<br>3333333333<br>3333333333
  </p>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Neither of them works. I updated the demo - https://codepen.io/magnix/pen/vdLReB I add more lines of info in each li. That is what I have on my actual project.

Comment: @ChristianLuneborg Updated my answer to solve that. Still, the chosen CSS Columns is a more dynamic solution.